# How integrate Paygreen (payment) with Laravel?

Tags: configuration, laravel-9

i have install paygreen with composer, but i don't know how configurate Paygreen with Laravel.
https://developers.paygreen.fr/docs/php-client
I don't know where i must write this code

I create variable on .env, i link this with admin backoffice
but i don't know how configurate and treat this data